# How can I load a style in GtkSourceView in python?

Tags: python, pygobject, gtksourceview

How can I load a new style in a GtkSourceView ?

In Gedit I can see it lists the styles found in `/usr/share/gtksourceview-3.0/styles`, how can I get my own GtkSourceView to load one of these styles ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`set_style_scheme()`](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#GtkSource-4/classes/Buffer.html#GtkSource.Buffer.set_style_scheme) method. Style schemes can be obtained from the [default `GtkSource.StyleSchemeManager` object](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#GtkSource-4/classes/StyleSchemeManager.html#GtkSource.StyleSchemeManager.get_default).